# Loop to get the name of every class using Selenium VBA

Tags: vba, loops, class, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to go through every "class" defined, and get his content (text).

I have code that takes the text from one class, and it doesn't continue with the other one.

It repeats the action 7 times, but just with the first class and doesn't show any error.

```vb
Dim bot As New WebDriver, myproducts As WebElements, myproduct As WebElement, i As Integer, productnum As String, clicknum As Integer, mysheet As Worksheet

i = 2
Set mysheet = Sheets("example2")
Set myproducts = bot.FindElementsByXPath("//h1[@class='minificha__nombre-producto']")
For Each myproduct In myproducts
    If myproduct.FindElementByXPath("//span[@class='minificha__sku ng-binding']").Text <> "" Then
        mysheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = myproduct.FindElementByXPath("//span[@class='minificha__sku ng-binding']").Text
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next
MsgBox ("complete")
End Sub
```

Comment: The output should be the text of that class, and it works, it gives me the text but it always give me the same name, it doesn't go through the others classes.

Comment: Yes, and this is the result.

Cód TG: AS0-322
Cód TG: AS0-322
Cód TG: AS0-322
Cód TG: AS0-322
Cód TG: AS0-322
Cód TG: AS0-322
Cód TG: AS0-322

It gives me the same code 7 times because there are 7 products but I need the code of each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want following sibling. The element you are after is not a child of myproduct. It is the adjacent sibling (same level next element).

```
myproduct.FindElementByXPath("following-sibling::span").Text
```

Comment: Jesus!, it works, can you explain me what the code means?, I want to understand each piece of the code, thanks you very much.

Comment: The element you are after is not a child of myproduct. It is the adjacent sibling (same level next element). So the above moves from myproduct to the following sibling span. You could additionally add in [@class='.....'] etc